# Error in using PHP fakers

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, laravel-seeding

I am trying to seed data as provided in this link https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker. The tables are filled but but I got this error:

```
    $ php artisan db:seed
    Seeding: gamesSeeder

  Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::issues does not exist.
```

I am running Lumen (5.6.3) (Laravel Components 5.6.*).

```
<?php


$factory->define(App\teams::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker-> word,
    ];
});

$factory->define(App\games::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'Team 1' => $faker-> word,
        'Team 2' => $faker-> word,
        'Score 1' => $faker->numberBetween($min = 0, $max = 10),
        'Score 2' => $faker->numberBetween($min = 0, $max = 10),
        'Game Date' => $faker->date($format = 'Y-m-d', $max = 'now'),
        'Viewers' => $faker-> numberBetween($min = 0, $max = 100000),
    ];
});
```

Here are my seeders files.
teamsSeeder:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class gamesSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {

        factory(App\games::class, 30)->create()->each(function($u) {
            $u->issues()->save(factory(App\games::class)->make());
          });
    }
}
```

and here is gamesSeeder

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\teams;

class teamsSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        factory(App\teams::class, 5)->create()->each(function($u) {
            $u->issues()->save(factory(App\teams::class)->make());
          });
    }
}
```

Comment: `'Viewers' => numberBetween($min = 0, $max = 100000),` Have you missed a `$faker->` here?

Comment: @zerkms Oh, yes. Thank you. But I still get an error even though the tables are filled:  ` Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::issues does not exist.`

Comment: can you update your post please

Comment: How long did you spend trying to fix this? The answer was in the error message...

Comment: Can you show some of the stack trace of the error and the actual seeder that calls the factories?

Comment: @Camilo I added that.

Comment: Where is `issues()` defined? Please add it to your question.